# How to communicate with clients from python socket server individually?

Tags: python, sockets

I'd like to be able to communicate individually with clients. When client will connect to server, it will send its name. On server I will type clients name and message and the message will go ONLY to the client with that name. This is what I have but it doesn't work:

SERVER:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket()
ip = "localhost"
port = 7000
s.bind((ip, port))
s.listen(5)
while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    name = c.recv(1024).decode()
    ask = input("Enter client's name: ")
    msg = input("Enter message: ")
    if name == ask:
        c.send(bytes(msg, 'utf-8'))
    else:
        print("No client with this name")
```

CLIENTS:

```
import socket
c = socket.socket()
ip = "localhost"
port = 7000
c.connect((ip, port))
name = "C1"
c.send(bytes(name, 'utf-8'))
while True:
    msg = c.recv(1024).decode()
    print(msg)
```

```
import socket
c = socket.socket()
ip = "localhost"
port = 7000
c.connect((ip, port))
name = "C2"
c.send(bytes(name, 'utf-8'))
while True:
    msg = c.recv(1024).decode()
    print(msg)
```

I will appreciate your advices :)

Comment: Your current server cannot handle two clients at the same time. It's synchronous.

Comment: So I need to import thread?

Comment: Yes, you need to use threads or coroutines, and you need to save the client name and the connection object between client and server.

Comment: Okay, I'll search something about thread and I'll try to implement it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following code is for your reference.

You need to be careful how to close the connection.

```py
import socket
import threading


s = socket.socket()
ip = "localhost"
port = 7000
s.bind((ip, port))
s.listen(5)

_map = {}


def get_recv(sock):
    name = sock.recv(1024).decode()
    _map.update({name: sock})


def send_msg():
    while True:
        ask = input("Enter client's name: ")
        msg = input("Enter message: ")
        sock = _map.get(ask)
        try:
            if sock:
                sock.send(bytes(msg, 'utf-8'))
            else:
                print("No client with this name")
        except BrokenPipeError:
            print("Client connection is broken.")
            sock.close()
            _map.pop(ask)


threading.Thread(target=send_msg, daemon=True).start()
while True:
    sock, addr = s.accept()
    threading.Thread(target=get_recv, args=(sock, ), daemon=True).start()
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm new to threading so it'll take me some time to go through the code but I think I got it :D

Comment: @Jane The implementation logic is more important than the implementation method, and hopefully it will help you.

Comment: Yea, sure. I'll try to understand the whole code. Thanks